# Synthesis of wand as and gate

Tags: verilog

Here I have multiple drivers for 1-bit port `x`. I want to resolve it by using `wand` net type. When I check out the schematics, only the least significant bit of input port is connected to port `x`, while remaining bits as unread. I want all bits of `a` to be used and assign to `x` port using AND gate to resolve multiple drivers.

```
module test(input [3:0]a, output [1:0]b);
  wire [3:0] d [1:0];

  wand temp;
  assign temp=a;

  inst inst_name (.x(temp),.y(d[1][3]),.z(b[1:0]));

  assign d[1] = {4'd15};
  assign d[0] = {4'd0};
endmodule

module inst (input wand x,y, output [1:0]z);
  assign z={x,y};
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for generate` loop to achieve what you want:

```
generate
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1) begin: wand_loop
    assign temp = a[i];
  end
endgenerate
```

This code will generate following structure:

[image]

Edit: as correctly pointed out by @mcleod_ideafix, if you define `temp` as a simple `wire` you can use following assignment: `assign temp = &a;` to achieve your goal.

Comment: Is this synthesizable?

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix: as you can see, it is.

Comment: So this is basically equivalent of doing `temp = &a;` where `temp` is defined as a regular `wire` instead of `wand`, isn't it?

Comment: was this structure drawn automatically by a synthesis program? If so, which is it? Thanks!

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix: you're right, but question was about usage of `wand` net. This image is from Altera Quartus II RTL Viewer.