# vectored input port driving output port of single bit net

Tags: verilog, equivalence

Why are these two codes not equivalent? I am checking the logical equivalence between the two, they are failing, what could be the error?
Will it take it as width mismatch, or net driven by multiple drivers? I am using cadence LEC for formal verification

```
module driver (a, b);
  input [3:0] a;
  output wand b;

  assign b = a;
endmodule
```

```
module driver (a, b);
  input [3:0] a;
  output wand b;

  assign b = a[3];
  assign b = a[2];
  assign b = a[1];
  assign b = a[0];
endmodule
```

Comment: In the end, the answer to this question is going to be similar to your [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555244/synthesis-of-wand-as-and-gate) one.

Answer (score 1):

`assign b = a` is equivalent to `assign b = a[0]`. The upper bits of `a` are out range for `b`.

Same reason with overflow. For example `assign sum[3:0]=a[3:0]+b[3:0]` if a=15 and b=2, sum will be 1 because there are not enough bits to represent 17 (17 mod (2^bitwidth(4)) = 1).